# Is there a way to construct a group of integers with a same feature that are easy to construct but difficult to guess?

Tags: algorithm, integer

As the title, is there a way to construct a group (about 100,000 pieces) of integers with a same feature that are easy to construct but difficult to guess?

For example, I thought constructing some 14-digit integers and let their sums of all 14 digits are all 70 is a good idea. However, it is hard to construct (seems like it is a NP problem) and easy to guess. So that I do not have an idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems a bit like an XY problem.  Please provide some context as to the use case.

Comment: Pseudo random integers? Easy to construct - `Random random = new Random(secretSeed); i_1 = random.Next(); ... i_100000 = random.Next();`, difficult to guess (providing that you have a good random generator, probably a cryptographic one)

Comment: Hashcodes for a each word in a secret text? Easy to construct - compute hash for each word, difficult to guess since (cryptographic) hash function is one way function (easy to compute, difficult to reverse)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I want to give people some codes and let them get gifts by using these codes. So they should be easy to construct but difficult to guess, and also easy to verify (sorry that I forget to say). So hashcode might not be a good idea. But you give me a inspiration: I can use both original text and hashed text then it would be easy to verify, too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @luogu_oddy Tip. Hash `text + secret` (with secret after).  That is still easy to verify, but nobody can duplicate the algorithm without knowing the `secret`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion that takes your idea one step further.

It is not NP-hard to create a random-looking 14-digit number with a digit sum equal to the expected average of 14 random digits, namely 14*4.5 = 63.

Use an integer array of size 14 and assign a random digit (between 0 and 9) to each index position. Then increment/decrement the digits at random index positions in steps of 1 until the digit sum becomes 63 (ensuring the digits stay between 0 and 9).

Now, making things more obscure, we assign 14 random digits to the array as before. This time, however, we let the 14'th digit point out the array position of a digit we leave untouched. We then calculate the digit sum of the 12 remaining digits and, as before, adjust it to the expected average, which is 12*4.5 = 54 this time.

So the 14-digit number is valid if the digit sum is 54 when omitting the 14'th digit and the digit it points out. The number will appear random, is easy to generate, and quite hard to guess. Furthermore, it is easy to check manually for validity, which may be an advantage.